# Can't configure OpenCV with Qt properly?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, opencv, mingw

I'm trying to configure OpenCV (3.1) with Qt Creator on Windows 32 and 64 bit for a long time to create a GUI application but I just can't seem to solve this configuration part. I've tried and read a lot of tutorials there are on the internet ([https://zahidhasan.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/qt-5-3-1-64-bit-mingw-windows/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kL0qfuLqB0U) for example) but with no success.

When I try to run my program, I'm getting these errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlrV6.jpg)

Comment: Seems like you forgot to tell QtCreator which OpenCV libs to link. Thats why you have those linker errors

Comment: they either forgot to link the libraries, or you are linking the wrong libraries (e.g. for a different compiler).

Answer (score 0):

To use a library, you have to reference its headers (and that is what you have done correctly with your `#include` directives). 
But you also have to point the linker to the location **and** names of libraries to link. That is currently missing in your configuration, because you get `undefined reference` errors from linker.
Hard to tell anything more without knowing more details on your setup so far.
Depending on your environment and the build of OpenCV you need, you need to configure your project to use static libraries or DLLs (I assume we speak about Windows here).
As you use `imread()`, you will surely need the opencv_highgui*.* library, but this will surely not suffice.
See e.g. this [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html) for a complete list of OpenCV libraries.

Comment: that's why this answer should be rather a comment than an answer ;)

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencvbuild\install\include\
LIBS += C:\opencvbuild\lib \
C:\opencvbuild\bin

PKGCONFIG += opencv

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui`

These are the contents of my .pro file. Where should I reference the headers?

Comment: @TheAdnan So what you use is probably a Qt project. The list of libraries may be quite long, depending on what you will use. I edited my answer to give more information.

Comment: @TheAdnan try to add `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc` etc. to the `LIBS` like this: `LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc`